# How to rename a deeply nested key in list of dictionaries (Python 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given the following dict (part of very long list of dicts):

```
{'diet': {'Diet 0': {'gender': 0,
   'nutrients': {'Alcohol': {'min': 0, 'max': 14, 'unit': 'oz'},
    'Caffeine': {'min': 0, 'max': 400, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Copper': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Calcium': {'min': 1000, 'max': 2500, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Choline': {'min': 425, 'max': 3500, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Cholesterol': {'min': 0, 'max': 300, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Fluoride': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'SaturatedFat': {'min': 0, 'max': -1, 'unit': 'g'},
    'VitaminA': {'min': 2330, 'max': 10000, 'unit': 'IU'},
    'VitaminC': {'min': 75, 'max': 2000, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminD': {'min': 15, 'max': 100, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'VitaminE': {'min': 15, 'max': 1000, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminK': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'VitaminB1': {'min': 1.1, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB2': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB5': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB3': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB6': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB12': {'min': 2.4, 'max': 999999999, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'Fiber': {'min': 21, 'max': 70, 'unit': 'g'},
    'Folate': {'min': 400, 'max': 1000, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'FolicAcid': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'Iodine': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'Iron': {'min': 18.0, 'max': 45, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Magnesium': {'min': 310, 'max': 350, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Manganese': {'min': nan, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Phosphorus': {'min': 700, 'max': 4000, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Potassium': {'min': 2600, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Selenium': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'Sodium': {'min': 500, 'max': 2300, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Sugar': {'min': nan, 'max': 24, 'unit': 'g'},
    'Zinc': {'min': 8.0, 'max': 40, 'unit': 'mg'}}}}}
```

I have 10000 of these dicts in a list, I want to change the `SaturatedFat` key to be `Saturated Fat`.
Tried with `ast`:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(str(diet_specs_dicts[0]).replace("'SaturatedFat':","'Saturated Fat':"))
```

Returns an error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 import ast
> ----> 2 ast.literal_eval(str(diet_specs_dicts[0]).replace("'SaturatedFat':","'Saturated
> Fat':"))
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in literal_eval(node_or_string)
> 97                     return left - right
> 98         return _convert_signed_num(node)
> ---> 99     return _convert(node_or_string)
> 100
> 101
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 86             if len(node.keys) != len(node.values):
> 87                 _raise_malformed_node(node)
> ---> 88             return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys),
> 89                             map(_convert, node.values)))
> 90         elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 86             if len(node.keys) != len(node.values):
> 87                 _raise_malformed_node(node)
> ---> 88             return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys),
> 89                             map(_convert, node.values)))
> 90         elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 86             if len(node.keys) != len(node.values):
> 87                 _raise_malformed_node(node)
> ---> 88             return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys),
> 89                             map(_convert, node.values)))
> 90         elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 86             if len(node.keys) != len(node.values):
> 87                 _raise_malformed_node(node)
> ---> 88             return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys),
> 89                             map(_convert, node.values)))
> 90         elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 86             if len(node.keys) != len(node.values):
> 87                 _raise_malformed_node(node)
> ---> 88             return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys),
> 89                             map(_convert, node.values)))
> 90         elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert(node)
> 96                 else:
> 97                     return left - right
> ---> 98         return _convert_signed_num(node)
> 99     return _convert(node_or_string)
> 100
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert_signed_num(node)
> 73             else:
> 74                 return - operand
> ---> 75         return _convert_num(node)
> 76     def _convert(node):
> 77         if isinstance(node, Constant):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _convert_num(node)
> 64     def _convert_num(node):
> 65         if not isinstance(node, Constant) or type(node.value) not in (int, float, complex):
> ---> 66             _raise_malformed_node(node)
> 67         return node.value
> 68     def _convert_signed_num(node):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py in _raise_malformed_node(node)
> 61         node_or_string = node_or_string.body
> 62     def _raise_malformed_node(node):
> ---> 63         raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
> 64     def _convert_num(node):
> 65         if not isinstance(node, Constant) or type(node.value) not in (int, float, complex):
>
> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at
> 0x7f17e20ca0a0>

Comment: You're probably better off using json. You can `json.dumps` the dictionary to turn it into a string, then do your str replace, then `json.loads` to get it back to a dictionary

Comment: Have you tried copying the value of 'SaturatedFat' into 'Saturated Fat', then deleting the original key with `my_dict.pop('key', None)`?

Comment: you've a variable "nan", what is the value?

Comment: @Yuri nan fixed. It should be 0.

Comment: @AimiHat yes, didn't work. It's a nested dict.

Comment: @C_Z_ Please give an example, it didn't work, says it can't serialise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive function that would change the key, wherever it occurred in the nested hierarchy:

*Edited for a typo in the function defintions*

```
>>> d = {'diet': {'Diet 0': {'gender': 0,
...:    'nutrients': {'Alcohol': {'min': 0, 'max': 14, 'unit': 'oz'},
...:     'Caffeine': {'min': 0, 'max': 400, 'unit': 'mg'},
...:     'SaturatedFat': {'min': 0, 'max': -1, 'unit': 'g'},
...:     'VitaminA': {'min': 2330, 'max': 10000, 'unit': 'IU'}}}}}

>>> def replace_key(d, old_key, new_key):
...:     for k, v in tuple(d.items()):
...:          if k == old_key:
...:              d[new_key] = d.pop(old_key)
...: 
...:          if isinstance(v, dict):
...:              replace_key(v, old_key, new_key)
...: 

>>> replace_key(d, old_key='SaturatedFat', new_key='Saturated Fat')
>>> d
{'diet': {'Diet 0': {'gender': 0,
   'nutrients': {'Alcohol': {'min': 0, 'max': 14, 'unit': 'oz'},
    'Caffeine': {'min': 0, 'max': 400, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminA': {'min': 2330, 'max': 10000, 'unit': 'IU'},
    'Saturated Fat': {'min': 0, 'max': -1, 'unit': 'g'}}}}}
```

This function changes the dictionary in-place, and returns `None`, but it is easily modified to return a copy, leaving the original dictionary unchanged:

```
>>> import copy
>>> def replace_key(d, old_key, new_key):
...:     d = copy.deepcopy(d)
...:     for k, v in tuple(d.items()):
...:          if k == old_key:
...:              d[new_key] = d.pop(old_key)
...: 
...:          if isinstance(v, dict):
...:              replace_key(v, old_key, new_key)
...: 
...:     return d
```

Comment: What is x here: ```x(v, old_key, new_key)```

Comment: Sorry - "x" is a typo. Should have been "replace_key". I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

here you go

```
lst = [{'diet': {'Diet 0': {'gender': 0,
   'nutrients': {'Alcohol': {'min': 0, 'max': 14, 'unit': 'oz'},
    'Caffeine': {'min': 0, 'max': 400, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Copper': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Calcium': {'min': 1000, 'max': 2500, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Choline': {'min': 425, 'max': 3500, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Cholesterol': {'min': 0, 'max': 300, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'Fluoride': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'SaturatedFat': {'min': 0, 'max': -1, 'unit': 'g'},
    'VitaminA': {'min': 2330, 'max': 10000, 'unit': 'IU'},
    'VitaminC': {'min': 75, 'max': 2000, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminD': {'min': 15, 'max': 100, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'VitaminE': {'min': 15, 'max': 1000, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminK': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mcg'},
    'VitaminB1': {'min': 1.1, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB2': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB5': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'},
    'VitaminB3': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'unit': 'mg'}, ............................]

for d in lst:
    d['Saturated Fat'] = d.pop('SaturatedFat')
print(lst)
```

Comment: I am sorry, it doesn't work. It says there is no such key:
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-80d329dbdb21> in <module>
----> 1 diet_specs_dicts[0].pop('SaturatedFat')

KeyError: 'SaturatedFat'```

Comment: can you post the complete error. I am not sure why you mentioned diet_specs_dicts[0] ...are you indent to replace only on "0" index??

Comment: In my case it's the list's name so I am taking the first (0) element and trying to change the key name. In your case the name of the list is lst.

Comment: post the complete error , will give the solution. The code works , may be small modification required .

Comment: Here I am taking the first 2 dicts in my list:
```lst = [diet_specs_dicts[0], diet_specs_dicts[1]]```
And running your solution:
```for d in lst:
    d['Saturated Fat'] = d.pop('SaturatedFat')```

Comment: Getting the following error:
```KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-cac4143e5eb4> in <module>
      2 
      3 for d in lst:
----> 4     d['Saturated Fat'] = d.pop('SaturatedFat')

KeyError: 'SaturatedFat'```

Comment: You can use the same dict twice if you want or modify one or 2 numbers there and name of the diet to diet 1.

Comment: that means 1st two dictionary does not have the SaturatedFat.  You can define default value before running the for loop if the key happens to not exist. you could define a default key as well:

d['SaturatedFat'] = d.pop('Saturated Fat', 'default_value')

Comment: They do exist...it's a nested dict it doesn't seem to work like this.

Comment: I have run your solution and it didn't work, just copied and pasted and nothing worked.